# How to change the executable in an OS X Application Bundle

Tags: firefox, macos

I would like to run a script before Firefox starts & after it quits. In Ubuntu I do this by creating a new shortcut that calls my function first, then calls the firefox command, then calls my last function. Since the firefox command blocks until the application quits, my last function is called immediately after the process ends.

However, in OS X I cannot do this as nicely because I end up with two icons on the dock. One for my script turned into an application & another for the Firefox application. I would prefer to just have one dock icon & to not break Firefox updates.

My current solution is to rename both MacOS/firefox{,-bin} to be prefixed with 'real-" and then name my shell script "firefox-bin". This works, but I am pretty sure that the next time firefox tries to update itself I am toast.

I have tried changing the "CFBundleExecutable" property in the bundle's Info.plist file to be my script, but that doesn't work.

Can anyone offer any other suggestions?

Comment: I figured out how to edit the "CFBundleExecutable" property in the Info.plist file. It seems that OS X caches the application information in ~/Library/Caches/Firefox . By deleting these caches I was able to get it to recognize my changes.

I changed the shell script to always open with "Terminal.app", and created a symlink without a file extension to the script inside of the Firefox.app/Content/MacOS/ folder. Then after setting the executable file to the name of the symlink it all works.

Not certain if Firefox updates will function, but this is easy enough to re/undo.

Comment: hi rob. i created an application bundle that launches firefox in antoher profile. i gave my bundle a custom icon. i run multiple profiles at once using `-no-remote`. so its normal to see one firefox logo for teh default and one for my custom profile. however sometimes the custom profile icon becomes the default icon. would you be available to chat sometime? i can show you screencast of my situation.

Comment: Hi @Rob what is the command you use to launch Firefox?

Comment: Sorry @Noitidart I am no longer doing things this way so I am not sure how this used to work.

Comment: Thanks very much @Rob for your reply I figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a regular application bundle but set `LSUIElement` on it, so the script application's icon is hidden from the dock, and include Firefox *inside* the bundle.

A simple way of doing this is with [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus).  Configure Platypus as follows:

- Click "Parameters".  Check the "Set
  $1 to path to application" checkbox,
  so your script can reference files
  inside the bundle.
- Check "Runs in background"—this sets
  `LSUIElement` for you.
- In the list of "Files and folders to
  be bundled with application into the
  Resources folder", drop Firefox.
- Change Output to "None" so your log
  messages go to the system console.
- Drop Firefox's icon file (firefox.icns) on the "Custom Icon" well.
- Change "App Name" to Firefox.

For a script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo before >&2
$1/Contents/Resources/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
echo after >&2
```

you get output like:

```
4/8/09 1:16:33 PM [0x0-0x801801].net.sabi.PlatypusScript[76610] before 
4/8/09 1:16:35 PM firefox-bin[76613] Database load time: 0.373 (717 objects) 
4/8/09 1:16:35 PM [0x0-0x801801].net.sabi.PlatypusScript[76610]
2009-04-08 13:16:35.699 firefox-bin[76613:10b] Database load time: 0.373 (717 objects) 
4/8/09 1:16:57 PM [0x0-0x801801].net.sabi.PlatypusScript[76610] after
```

If your users launch Firefox in other ways, such as with URL handlers and by opening HTML files, you'll instead need to use a native application, which can pass the appropriate Apple Events through to Firefox, and add the appropriate URL and file handler information to the Info.plist.  ([aemreceive](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/install.html) is a convenient Python wrapper for Apple Event reception.)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, I just needed the bit about how to hide an icon from the dock. Danke!

Comment: An issue with this solution is that you cannot see the Firefox menu bar anymore. I found a better one above.

Comment: I have a similar situation @Nicholas but my thing is, when i click my app bundle it launches firefox with command line arguments `-no-remote -P "my second profile"`. So this is good, but if i do `killall Dock; killall Finder` it seperates my one icon into two. Ill make a video demo'ing this if needed, but do you know how to make firefox believe my app bundle icon is its icon. I think this is similar to what you shared here.

Comment: Hi @Rob and Nicholas, this youtube video screencast i made shows that if i type in terminal `killall Finder; killall Dock` it is disociating my appbundle icon from the firefox icon in the dock, clearly seen by the icon change, as my appbundle has a differnt icon. [Youtube :: Demo of Problem where AppBundle of Firefox Seperates from Firefox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJR6HDpjfxc). Now I know you all are saying just dont type that in terminal, but I have to test all cases because my firefox addon is a multi profile shortcut creator. Please advise on how i can make keep association.

Comment: @Rob and Nicholad a real situation where this icon splits is when a user restarts firefox with one of the restart methods. (for example devs typically restart with Shift + F2 and in ff command line type "restart" no quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Automator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)) workflow if available on your version of Mac OS.

Comment: When you launch an application it always creates an icon on the dock. I would prefer there only be one so as not to be confusing.

I mentioned that I already have an application version of my script and I don't like that method.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the clarification. I was confused (I didn't see that you don't two icons at _runtime_).

Comment: @dirkgently: np, I think your solution is the only one that I am going to be able to go with. But I am still hoping some guru will come by with a few dollops of knowledge for me.