# Extract application icons from Desktop folder to application

Tags: java, swing, icons

Is it possible to read the icons from a computer's desktop folder and display them in an application?

**EDIT:** What I mean by "icon" is retrieving the image used to display. Reason being is that some program don't use direct shortcut images by default or a user ops to not create a shortcut when installing a program. As I've already checked my folder, I've noticed icons such as these based on their properties (Type of file):

- Safari - *.lnk
- Photoshop - *.png
- Visual Studio - *.exe

All of these display their icons in some sort of way (png is obviously the easiest), but where this non-image extensions resides isn't exactly clear.

Comment: You should be able to load icons from any folder as long as you know their path. Did you try it?

Comment: @Sudhanshu I have that done already. I updated the question to be more clear about the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no cross-platform API for retrieving application-specific or user-substituted icons. For specific platforms, look at [Windows](https://superuser.com/q/25086) and [Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646671/230513).

Alternatively, consider [`FileSystemView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html), which is "the gateway to the file system" used by `JFileChooser`. It abstracts many of the platform-specific icons used by the file system. Several examples that use the facility are illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15150756/230513).