# GarageBand, Audio Units, and Custom Icons

Tags: audiounit

I've created an audio unit that I will be exclusively using in GarageBand. I'd like to link it to a custom icon I've created, so that when I select my audio unit, the custom icon will show in the instrument window and/or the track pane. I've seen that others have asked the question on this forum (and many other forums) in the past, but the answers were insufficient. I wonder now that several updates of GarageBand have been available, that there might be an answer to this question.

I know that I could just copy my custom icon into an existing icon's place, but that won't work for me because, say I replace their "bird" icon with my custom icon and then say I select a "bird sound" as a track. The custom icon will show instead of the "bird" icon because I replaced it. You can see that it can get very confusing.

Any help with this would be very appreciated, even if it means just pointing me in a direction.

Thanks,
-Lisa Marie

Comment: If you set an icon for your AU in the bundle (ie, so you can see the icon in the Finder), does that also appear in GB? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646671/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-applications-mac-os-x-app-bundle