# Sublime text is running with an incorrect PATH environment variable

Tags: sublimetext2

If I run the following in the console, it outputs '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin':

```
import os  
os.environ['PATH']
```

But everywhere else the PATH is correct. In both `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` and if I run `launchctl getenv PATH` I get the correct path.

This is preventing me from running CoffeeCompile. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and did not find a way to pass down the correct PATH. However, **I have a workaround**: It seems to work with the correct PATH as soon as you open Sublime Text from a shell. In other words:

1. Follow [this tip](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) to create a shell shortcut to Sublime Text. This is optional, but comes in handy.
2. Create a Workflow as described [in the answer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281372/executing-shell-scripts-from-the-os-x-dock), with a shell script to open Sublime Text (using the above created `subl` command, or directly). That way you can open ST from your Dock.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty text file called "Sublime Text.sh" in the Sublime Text application bundle directory

```
/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Open the Sublime Text.sh in a text editor and enter the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ~/.bash_profile

logger "`dirname \"$0\"`/Sublime Text"

exec "`dirname \"$0\"`/Sublime Text" $@
```

In the Terminal set the executable flag of the shell script eclipse.sh, i.e.:

```
chmod +x /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text.sh
```

Open the Sublime Text.app Info.plist and change the value for the key CFBundleExecutable from Sublime Text to Sublime Text.sh.

MacOS X does not automatically detect that the Sublime Text.app's Info.plist has changed. Therefore you need to force update the LaunchService database in the Terminal by using the lsregister command:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/eclipse/Sublime Text.app
```

The next time you launch Sublime Text.app from the Dock or from the Finder the environment variables should be set.

This will make it so that when you open Sublime Text.app it will run your shell script instead of the Sublime Text executable.

Your shell script then executes .bash_profile (setting the path) and starts the Sublime Text executable with that path.